# Strange working of ceil() function (php)

Tags: php, ceil

This code:

```
echo (40 * (10 / 100 + 1)); //44
echo (50 * (10 / 100 + 1)); //55
echo ceil(40 * ((10 / 100) + 1)); //44
echo ceil(50 * ((10 / 100) + 1)); //56 (!)
```

I think, that "56" by reason of floating point (55.0000000001 => 56), but I can't understood why for "40" result is "44", not "45"

Comment: You can learn more about this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Comment: @MayurKoshti It doesn't look to me like he doesn't understand the function. It is actually pretty odd this is happening as `50 * ((10 / 100) + 1)` equals 55 perfectly. It's not a float. So it shouldn't round it up to 56 in the first place.

Comment: @NikitaKolosov: can you print the value of each intermediate step separately and see where it might've gone wrong?

Comment: I tested and getting same. :(

Comment: Yes, that's because of the [floating point errors](http://floating-point-gui.de/). In you case, if for the case of "`56`", the number is actually sth about `56.000000001`; then, for the case of "`40`", the number is actually something sth about `39.999999999`!

Comment: @someOne No it isn't. `sprintf('%.50f', $y);` (assuming $y is the math) returns exactly 40.0000.. etc :P

Comment: @icecub then for the case of "`40`", the number is actually something sth about `39.999999999` _or simply and accurately (mathematically wise) is equal to "`40`"! (i.e. it's one the cases where the decimal number can be accurately be represented in the binary format)_ :)

Comment: @someOne I took a moment to read that document real quick (amazing reference btw!) and it explains why some floats are calculated perfectly and others not. Thanks a lot for that :)

Answer (score 5):

The 55 isn’t actually 55. You can verify that easily:

```
<?php
$x = (40 * (10 / 100 + 1)); // 44
$y = (50 * (10 / 100 + 1)); // 55
echo '$x == 44: ' . ($x == 44 ? 'True' : 'False') . "\n";
echo '$y == 55: ' . ($y == 55 ? 'True' : 'False') . "\n";
echo '$y > 55: ' . ($y > 55 ? 'True' : 'False') . "\n";
echo $y - 55;
```

Yields:

```
$x == 44: True
$y == 55: False
$y > 55: True
7.105427357601E-15
```

As you can see the difference is tiny (7.1 * 10^-15) but that still makes it larger than 55, so `ceil` will round it up.

The reason you just see `55` is because echoing it will convert the float [into a string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

> String conversion is automatically done in the scope of an expression where a string is needed. This happens when using the echo or print functions, or when a variable is compared to a string.

For this conversion the standard truncating behavior will cut off the digits at some point. This is configured by the [`precision` configuration parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) and defaults to 14. You can avoid this behavior by using `sprintf` with a custom precision:

```
echo sprintf('%.50f', $y);
// 55.00000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125000
```

Comment: So why does `abs($y)` return 55?

Comment: @icecub `abs()` does not change the number but only the sign. so `abs($y)` for a positive `$y` gives you the same number. It’s just shown as `55`, because printing the number truncates the digits at some point.

Comment: I see. Still I find it a bit odd as I've always thought `abs()` returns the absolute number no matter the amount of floating point digits. Also looking from a math perspective, it should simply be 55 :P Anyway, thanks for explaining!

Comment: @icecub `abs()` just returns the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of a number. It has nothing to do with floats or decimals. And if there was a magic function that fixed incorrect float point issues: How would that function decide whether a number is off the integer by accident or by design? ;)

Comment: Yeye, enough messing with my head already! Haha. I seriously even start thinking about it /cry

Comment: Sorry for being lazy, but why is $x exactly 44 but $y not exactly 55? Aren't both variables affected by the same shortcomings of floating point representation by binary mantissa?

Comment: @klaar It’s just a happy coincidence that multiplicating the floating point representation of `10 / 100 + 1` by 40 yields back to a precise floating point number while `50` doesn’t. It’s difficult to understand since the multiplication works with the binary representation while we think of it as “integer times broken float” (which should almost never give an integer back)

Comment: I can't understood why it working only for '50'. Why for other numbers it is ok.

Comment: @NikitaKolosov You mean 40. But it works for other numbers too, e.g. `5`, `20`, `35`, `60`. It’s due to how floating point numbers are represented in memory (as sums of exponentials of 2^x). It just happens to be that some multiplications get rid of the imprecisions while most others don’t.

Answer (score 1):

We need to notice **Floating point precision**
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

> Rational numbers that are exactly representable as floating point
>   numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an exact
>   representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is used
>   internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they cannot be
>   converted into their internal binary counterparts without a small loss
>   of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for example,
>   floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the expected 8,
>   since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....

And this is the answers for the question **Why don’t my numbers add up?** http://floating-point-gui.de/ . Explain concisely why you get that unexpected result